# Change aria-valuenow Kendo UI input

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

So I have an imput to capture weight. When I click on edith I want the input to show me the information. It does shows it. But only when I click on it.

When the page loads the input stays with its aria-valuenow = 0.

```
<input type="text" class="k-formatted-value k-input" title="0.00 kg" 
tabindex="0" role="spinbutton" aria-valuenow="0" aria-disabled="false" 
style="font-size: 18px;">
```

I've tried to change it with Jquery and the attribute arr but it does not work.

```
$("#weight").attr('aria-valuenow', cow.weight);
```

Anyone who can help me out with this? Please.

Answer (score 1):

So I totally forgot that I asked this. I solved it searching a little bit more in the web.

```
        $('#weight').data("kendoNumericTextBox").value(goat.weight);
        $('#weight').data("kendoNumericTextBox").trigger("change");
```

If there is anyone needing this.